# Import all csv files into a table oracle

Tags: oracle, linux, scripting

Trying to import all the files into a table but I receive the following error.

```
#!/bin/bash 
. ~/.bash_profile 
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1
sqlldr USERID=user/pass@mydb DATA=/data/SDP/Import/*.csv \
    CONTROL=/home/path/test.ctl LOG=/home/path/test.log
```

Error Message

```
 SQL*Loader-500: Unable to open file  (/path/path/Import/*.csv) 
 SQL*Loader-553: file not found 
 SQL*Loader-509: System error: No such file or directory 
 SQL*Loader-2026: the load was aborted because SQL Loader cannot  continue.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use a shell loop, instead of trying to pass a wildcard:

```
#!/bin/bash 
. ~/.bash_profile 
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1

for FILE in /data/SDP/Import/*.csv; do
    sqlldr USERID=user/pass@mydb "DATA=$FILE" \
        CONTROL=/home/path/test.ctl LOG=/home/path/test.log
    done
```

Comment: I changed list in for loop so that special characters in file names like blanks are handled collrectly.. Some problems remain: I think that sqlldr overwrites the log ofthe prevoius run whenever it is executed. Also the the environment is not set correctly if only ORACLE_HOME is set but not the PATH and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is adapted. But maybe they are set in the .bash_profile.